# LINQ joining multiple lists

Tags: c#, linq

I want to be able to join multiple lists. What I'm trying to do is to reply to a user with the best suitable answer. To do this the program reads a sentence typed in by the user, stores infinitives, nouns, articles and adverbs in seperate lists and tries to find the best answer or reply for the user in a list of structs with pre-defined answers by joining the lists.

So list1 (the answer list) looks like this

```
public struct ll
{
    int index;
    string infinitive;
    string noun;
    string article;
    string adverb;
    string preposition;
    string answer;        
}
public List <ll> list1;
```

with below data:

[image]

When for example the user inputs the sentence **"what can you find"** the join script should return two possible answers, being **"I can find this information"** and **"What do you want me to find"**, because only an infinitive can be found in the users input and no noun, article, adverb, etc.

But when the sentence is more explicit like **"what can you find here"**, it would only return **"I can find this information"**, so the search was done on infinitive in combination with an adverb.

Also when the user asks: **"what do you know about THIS hobbit"** it would return nothing as the combination **"know"** and **"this"** is unknown, where as **"what do you know about hobbit"** would return with **"This I know about"**

I'm trying to accomplish this with a LINQ join statement like

```
var query = from x in answer
            join y1 in infinitive on x.infinitive equals y1
            join y2 in noun on x.noun equals y2
            join y3 in adverb on x.adverb equals y3
            etc...
            select x.index;
```

the problem with this however is that in case the user types in something like **"what do you know ABOUT the hobbit"** it will return nothing because it's trying to match the user's infinitive **"know"** in combination with the preposition **"about"**, where it should answer **"This I know about"**.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: You should give code to initialize "list1" with your sample data instead of an image, it will be helpful. And the question is not clear, as the way your user is supposed to type something.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . In particular, include the source code to setup the sample input data. And be really explicit about the expected **output** for the sample input data.

Comment: Your described rules are inconsistent. You expect "what can you find" to register a hit on the rule with **both** "find" and "here", even though "here" is not part of the sentence. But then in your other example, "what do you know about THIS hobbit", you expect it to not hit the row with "know" and "hobbit" because "this" is not explicitly mentioned there. That is contradictory behavior. Either the rules must allow for half-matches, or they don't (thus requiring ALL defined words to be found). If you want to compromise inbetween, you need to clarify when a word is required and when it isn't.